# Not able to install Nuget packages in Rider

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, rider, nuget-package-restore

I am trying to install Microsoft.Identity.Web Nuget package in rider for a .Net Coren application.
But, I am getting the error below:

```
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ABC.WebAPI'. Package 
'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 4.0.20710' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Ve ... e package directly from the project to select a different version. ABC.WebAPI -> Microsoft.Identity.Web 1.25.10 -> Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCache 1.25.10 -> Microsoft.Identity.Client (>= 4.46.0) ABC.WebAPI -> Microsoft.Identity.Client (>= 4.43.2)
```

I tried to clear Nuget caches and also tried to invalidate caches and restart option couple of times but it did not work. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Looks like it is target framework incompatibility issue. Could you take a look on the detailed log? And provide any additional info

Answer (score 0):

I was somehow able to install the  Microsoft.Identity.Web Nuget 1.24.1 instead of 1.25.0 which worked out for me. Thanks.